# How to create an new column in R based on value from repeated headers in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: r, excel, header

I am trying to read in multiple excel spreadsheets in which the data is organized into tables. (Example of what the spreadsheet looks like currently in the image):

[Data in Excel to be transformed in R, has repeated tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiysb.png)

I need the experimental unit (cow) as its own column in analysis, but it is only located in the header of each table. Any ideas of the best way to rearrange the data in R? The first row of the spreadsheet is also read in as the column names, which I obviously don't really want either. Here is a reproducible example of what the sheet looks like when read into R:

```
r1<-c("id","Cow 5590","...2","...3","Control","...4","...5","...6","...7","...8")
r2<-c("","","date","day","intake1","intake2","eattime","visits","dmi","vtime")
r3<-c("1","","43173","-21","24384","14.6","214","10","1.46","21.4")
r4<-c("1"," ","43174","-20","24374","17.6","217","17","1.76","27.4")
r5<-c("id","Cow 5591","...2","...3","Control","...4","...5","...6","...7","...8")
r6<-c("","","date","day","intake1","intake2","eattime","visits","dmi","vtime")
r7<-c("1"," ","43173","-21","24364","15.6","234","12","1.36","22.4")
r8<-c("1"," ","43174","-20","24884","18.6","284","18","1.86","28.4")
r9<-c("id","Cow 5592","...2","...3","Control","...4","...5","...6","...7","...8")
r10<-c("","","date","day","intake1","intake2","eattime","visits","dmi","vtime")
r11<-c("1"," ","43173","-21","24564","15.5","234","15","1.56","24.4")
r12<-c("1"," ","43174","-20","24584","15.6","254","18","1.85","34.4")

df<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=11))
colnames(df)<-r1
df[1,]<-r2
df[2,]<-r3
df[3,]<-r4
df[4,]<-r5
df[5,]<-r6
df[6,]<-r7
df[7,]<-r8
df[8,]<-r9
df[9,]<-r10
df[10,]<-r11
df[11,]<-r12
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
c1<-c("id","Cow", "date","day","intake1","intake2","eattime","visits","dmi","vtime")
c2<-c("1","Cow 5590","43173","-21","24384","14.6","214","10","1.46","21.4")
c3<-c("1","Cow 5590","43174","-20","24374","17.6","217","17","1.76","27.4")
c4<-c("1","Cow 5591","43173","-21","24364","15.6","234","12","1.36","22.4")
c5<-c("1","Cow 5591","43174","-20","24884","18.6","284","18","1.86","28.4")
c6<-c("1","Cow 5592","43173","-21","24564","15.5","234","15","1.56","24.4")
c7<-c("1","Cow 5592","43174","-20","24584","15.6","254","18","1.85","34.4")

df2<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=6))
colnames(df2)<-c1
df2[1,]<-c2
df2[2,]<-c3
df2[3,]<-c4
df2[4,]<-c5
df2[5,]<-c6
df2[6,]<-c7
```

First time poster. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
df %>%
    mutate(`Cow 5590` = na_if(trimws(`Cow 5590`), "")) %>%
   fill(`Cow 5590`) %>% 
   mutate(`Cow 5590` = replace_na(`Cow 5590`, "Cow 5590")) %>% 
   mutate(id = replace(id, 1, 'id')) %>%
   row_to_names(1) %>% 
   filter(!id  %in% c("id", "")) %>% 
   rename(Cow = `Cow 5590`) %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
id      Cow  date day intake1 intake2 eattime visits  dmi vtime
1  1 Cow 5590 43173 -21   24384    14.6     214     10 1.46  21.4
2  1 Cow 5590 43174 -20   24374    17.6     217     17 1.76  27.4
3  1 Cow 5591 43173 -21   24364    15.6     234     12 1.36  22.4
4  1 Cow 5591 43174 -20   24884    18.6     284     18 1.86  28.4
5  1 Cow 5592 43173 -21   24564    15.5     234     15 1.56  24.4
6  1 Cow 5592 43174 -20   24584    15.6     254     18 1.85  34.4
```

Comment: I had no idea that this "fill" function existed, thank you so much!